# How to convert NSString to NSObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsobject

In my project i need to compare and NSString with NSObject. How to convert NSString to NSObject. OR Is there any chance to compare NSString with NSObject.

Comment: can you explain it further? why need to compare with NSObject? or are you talking about comparing if an NSString is an NSObject type?

Comment: NSString is NSObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString class itself inherits from NSObject class, So you can directly compare them, see below code or check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
NSString *str = @"xyz";
NSObject *obj = @"xyz";

if([str isEqualToString:(NSString *)obj]) {
     NSLog(@"comparision successful");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your NSObject is indeed an NSString, you can just cast it;

```
NSString *text = (NSString*)someObject;
```

Where someObject is the object you want to be a string. If you're not sure if the object is an NSString, you can check by doing the following;

```
if ([someObject class] == [NSString class){
    NSString *text = (NSString*)someObject;
}
```

Hope that helps.